# Email piping vs forwarding

Tags: email

I am working on a project where we need the mails from our mail server to our system.

For this i did some research on internet. And I came across two terms **email piping** and **email forwarding**.

Can anyone through some light on these two terms.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sys admin type question - should be on ServerFault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean..."to our system" but piping from what I recall refers to automatically processing the email and using it as data in some way.  For example you might take emails and use the body as part of a help-desk ticket.

Forwarding will just push the email to another place.

Answer (score 1):

It is nowadays just the same.

Piping is forwarding the email to a program (like "filter" or "procmail" under *nix) which then filters/resend/copies/bounces it.

Forwarding (re)sends you mail to another adress. For sendmail-based systems that could be achieved by just putting the adress into a .forward-file. It is not really different from piping, as forwarding too requires a program on the mail-server/client that manages the forwarding.